# Book where the main character is sent away with a traveling mage, in exchange for rain to end a drought

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, magic

What is the name of the book where the main character is given to a traveling mage in exchange for rain to end a drought? I started reading the novel ( young adult novel I think) but never finished it. I believe the main character was a teen or young adult. She was unexpectedly sent away by her family, after a stranger with magic promised to give them rain. I believe the magician was not a villain and was trying to help the girl.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Answer (score 3):

[Brightly Woven](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6580510-brightly-woven) by Alexandra Braken.

[image: Brightly Woven]

> Just as the rains come after ten long, dry years, a young wizard, Wayland North, appears, to whisk Sydelle Mirabil away from her desert village. North needs an assistant, and Sydelle is eager to see the country - and to join him on his quest to stop the war that surely will destroy her home. But North has secrets - about himself, about why he chose Sydelle, about his real reasons for the journey. What does he want from her? And why does North's sworn enemy seem fascinated by Sydelle himself?

After the drought ends and the mysterious Mr. North appears Sydelle is told by her father:

> “I offered Mr. North a reward for breaking the drought,” my father explained, “and he’s chosen you. Do you understand?”

The two of them set off to rescue the kingdom from invasion by the neighbouring kingdom of *Auster* and to restore the Queen to the throne.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like one of the sub-stories in Katherine Kerr's Deverry series.

In the first book Daggerspell, we come across the beginning of Aderyn's story set in 698. This is early enough in the book and series to be mistaken for the introduction of an entire novel.

Aderyn's not the main character, so that doesn't match the question. The main character is the mage Nevyn. He's come to Aderyn's town in order end the drought and Aderyn ends up leaving with him to train as a mage or Dweomermaster in the local terminology.

More details that might jog the memories.

Aderyn's father is the local bard, he has to attempt a dream vision to see if a curse exists or a god is angry and causing the drought.

His vision is of a murder and he is asked by the god providing the vision if he thought the vengeance on the murderer was sufficient.

This is relevant because the Bard is the reincarnation of the murder victim. A member of the local warband is a reincarnation of the murderer and Aderyn's mother is the reincarnation of the woman they were fighting over.

Comment: Actually spotted the gender and evil nature of the mage and this is unlikely to be right. Leaving it here in case it helps someone with a similar question in the future.